# is is possible to bind TCP socket to many ports?

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming

I see that some applications using TCP can be configured to bind to multiple ports. Does this mean that they open multiple TCP sockets, or it is possible to open a single socket and bind it to many local ports?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A TCP socket can only be bound to a single port.  In particular, if you try to bind an already-bound TCP socket to a second port, `bind()` will return -1 and set `errno` to `EINVAL`.

Servers that accept incoming TCP connections on multiple ports are doing it by creating multiple TCP sockets.